# Sum method in LINQ with long type

Tags: c#, linq

How can I get sum of some items in long type... here is mycode :

```
using (gEn myEntities = new gEn)
{
var load = (from items in myEntities.Orders
select items.PayO).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum();
}
```

but the Sum gives me int... I also wants to know if DefaultIfEmpty method has any conflict with Sum method when use it for long type... thanks in advance...

Comment: I wonder if the `0` in `DefaultIfEmpty(0)` is being interpreted as an `int` a change the resultant type?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) returns whatever type the expression used in the `select` returns (provided it's one of the defined overloads).  If you want to return a long then cast `items.PasO`:

```
var load = (from items in myEntities.Orders
            select (long)(items.PayO)
           )
           .DefaultIfEmpty(0).Sum();
```

> I also wants to know if DefaultIfEmpty method has any conflict with Sum method when use it for long type

No, `DefaultIfEmpty` works with *any* type, including `long`.  As long as there's a `Sum` overload for that type it works just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much... It works well... I'll mark this as answer... :)

Answer (score 3):

If `Sum()` returns an `int` it's because that's the data type of your collection. All these LINQ to Object methods are generic. And no, `DefaultIfEmpty` will have no side effects. It's just going to give you 0 if there are no items in the collection, then `Sum` is going to work on the result of that which is going to be an `IEnumerable<int>` with a single item which will have a value of 0.

I'm just assuming you're using EF here. If that is the case you need to either do a cast after you retrieve the data or change your model on the C# side so that it has `long`. You may also want to check what the data type for that table is because if you generated your C# model from the data source and it's using an int32, then that's probably what your table has too.

Comment: my database uses int32... but it has to be int64 for Sum, otherwise It gives me wrong result... since we can cast it(and you mention that), there is no problem... and thank you for answering:)