# LINQ Group by & SUM to a LONG variable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

```
long  BOQ_Val = (from Boq_table in ctx.tbl_BOQ
                 where (boq_locationID == Boq_table.Location_ID
                        && boq_Code_ID == Boq_table.WorkCode_ID)
                 group Boq_table by Boq_table.WorkCode_ID into g
                 select new 
                        { 
                           units_Total = (long)g.Sum(x => x.Units) 
                        });
```

Hi 
i am getting the error as

> > "cannot implicitly convert type system.linq.iqueryable to long"

Please  help me
i need's units total (where the above condition) into a long variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848490/sum-method-in-linq-with-long-type

Comment: How about moving the cast to long inside the sum? `g.Sum(x => (long)x.Units)`

Comment: What's the type of `x.Units`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of your query is an `IQueryable<long>` while you want your `BOQ_Val` to be a `long`.

You first filter by `WorkCodeId`, which gives you an `IQueryable<BOQ_Table>` and then you group your `BOQ`'s by `WorkCodeId`. That leaves you an `IQueryable<IGrouping<int, long>>`, where the key is the `WorkCode_Id`. From each grouping you select the `long`, leaving you with an `IQueryable<long>`. You and I both know that there is at most one result, because you grouped over a variable that you filtered over earlier, but C# doesn't know that, so you have to pick out that one result.

What the nicest way to re-write that is up to you. If you already filter on `boq_Code_ID` with `where`, you no longer have to group by it, so one way would be

```
long  BOQ_Val = (from Boq_table in ctx.tbl_BOQ
                 where (boq_locationID == Boq_table.Location_ID
                     && boq_Code_ID == Boq_table.WorkCode_ID)
                 ).Sum(Boq_table => (long)Boq_table.Units);
```

personally I like the full extension methods more (I think it's clearer that way. I seem to be a minority though). Going that way would give you

```
long  BOQ_Val = ctx.tbl_BOQ.Where(Boq_table => 
                     (boq_locationID == Boq_table.Location_ID &&
                      boq_Code_ID == Boq_table.WorkCode_ID)
                 ).Sum(Boq_table => (long)Boq_table.Units);
```

If `Boq_table.Units` is already a long, the typecast does nothing here. If it's an int, it might be needed to prevent overflow. If that's the goal of the cast, it needs to be on the inside of the `Sum`, otherwise you would just cast your overflown wrapped around `int` to a `long`, which would do absolutely nothing.

Comment: Thanking you Very Much Mr.Martijn

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your query to:

```
long  BOQ_Val = (from Boq_table in ctx.tbl_BOQ
                   where (boq_locationID == Boq_table.Location_ID
                           && boq_Code_ID == Boq_table.WorkCode_ID)
                   group Boq_table by Boq_table.WorkCode_ID into g
                   select g.Sum<long>(x => x.Units)).FirstOrDefault();
```

There is no need to create anonymous class object in Select stement when you only want to get sum.

And about this construction:

```
units_Total = (long)g.Sum(x => x.Units)
```

Assuming that Units is of type int, casting Sum to long makes no sense because this method would produce sum which would be in int value range. 
That's way you should use:

```
g.Sum<long>(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you just use a `cast<long>`and pick your fist item

```
 long  BOQ_Val = (from Boq_table in ctx.tbl_BOQ
                       where (boq_locationID == Boq_table.Location_ID
                               && boq_Code_ID == Boq_table.WorkCode_ID)
                       group Boq_table by Boq_table.WorkCode_ID into g
                       select new { units_Total = g.Sum<long>(x => x.Units) }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Well he just need to pick the first item

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault`, as you are expecting only one value.

```
 long  BOQ_Val = (from Boq_table in ctx.tbl_BOQ
                       where (boq_locationID == Boq_table.Location_ID
                               && boq_Code_ID == Boq_table.WorkCode_ID)
                       group Boq_table by Boq_table.WorkCode_ID into g
                       select new { units_Total = g.Sum(x => x.Units) }).FirstOrDefault();
```