# Sum method return long value

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get LINQ `Sum` method result as `long`.

```
long TotalWeight = _ctx.ProductsToUsers.Where(pu => pu.UserId == subDetails.user.Id).SelectMany(pu => pu.CropData).Sum(cd => cd.Weight);
```

In above code snippet, `Weight` is of type `int`. Now I want to add all the weights and store them in a `TotalWeight` variable. The problem is that the sum might exceed range of `int` so I must convert it to `long`.

I tried the following code:

```
long TotalWeight = _ctx.ProductsToUsers.Where(pu => pu.UserId == subDetails.user.Id).SelectMany(pu => pu.CropData).Sum(cd => (long)cd.Weight);
```

But above code is giving me an error of `unable to cast object of type 'system.int32' to type 'system.int64'`. How do I convert sum of `Weight` to `long` without losing data?

Converting `Weight` to type `long` is not feasible solution because single `Weight` is never going to exceed `int` range.

Below is implementation of `CropData` class.

```
public class CropData
{
    [Required]
    public int ProductToUserId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Weight { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't give error to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum method in LINQ with long type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848490/sum-method-in-linq-with-long-type)

Comment: You can't possibly have given us enough info here. The code you have posted will work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long TotalWeight = _ctx.ProductsToUsers.Where(pu => pu.UserId == subDetails.user.Id)
        .SelectMany(pu => pu.CropData).Sum(cd => Convert.ToInt64(cd.Weight));
```

Comment: How is this any different from OPs code? Other than the fact that now Entity Framework will complain about not understanding `Convert.ToInt64`?

Comment: Convert.ToInt64(cd.Weight)

Comment: Yes, that's the same as a direct cast here, but now you've introduced an Entity Framework error too.

Comment: `(long)cd.Weight` and `Convert.ToInt64(cd.Weight)` suppose to be same. But `Convert.ToInt64(cd.Weight)` does not give an error to me but `(long)cd.Weight` gives an error to me.

Answer (score 3):

I can give you an answer that may work:

```
long TotalWeight = _ctx.ProductsToUsers.Where(pu => pu.UserId == subDetails.user.Id).SelectMany(pu => pu.CropData.Weight).Cast<long>().Sum();
```

However, I am more interested in why your solution didn't work. Let's take a look:

```
long TotalWeight = _ctx.ProductsToUsers.Where(pu => pu.UserId == subDetails.user.Id).SelectMany(pu => pu.CropData).Sum(cd => (long)cd.Weight);
```

It matches the signature of `Enumerable.Sum`:

```
public static long Sum<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, long> selector
)
```

and at runtime, it is perfectly legal to convert an instance of `int` to an instance of `long`. The problem lies in your ORM's implementation of `IQueryable`. Linq to Entities (or whatever your ORM is using) cannot properly interpret the cast

```
cd => (long)cd.Weight
```

The fact that it is your ORM that is causing the problem explains why several people are reporting that it works for them.

Another way to solve this is to throw in a `ToArray()` call, which will tell your ORM to load all of your `CropData` objects into memory. Then the Linq operation will be performed on your in-memory objects:

```
long TotalWeight = _ctx.ProductsToUsers.Where(pu => pu.UserId == subDetails.user.Id).SelectMany(pu => pu.CropData)
    .ToArray()
    .Sum(cd => (long)cd.Weight);
```

This means that you're downloading the unused fields `ProductToUserId` and `DateTime` as well -- maybe not a problem here, but if your `CropData` object were much bigger, there would be a performance hit. Therefore, whatever else you decide to do, I would recommend you use `SelectMany(pu => pu.CropData.Weight)`, which will keep your data transfer costs down to a minimum.

Comment: Converting it to array then calling `.Sum(cd => (long)cd.Weight)` also works for me. Amount of `CropData` object will be high so I can't load them all into memory. `Convert.ToInt64(cd.Weight)` also works for me which does not require to load `cropdata` into memory so I will stick to `Convert.ToInt64(cd.Weight)`

Comment: That sounds like the best way to do it. By using `Convert.ToInt64`, you're delegating the summation command to your data store, and the only thing you're transferring into memory is the final result. It's important to understand why this is happening, as well as how to fix it.

Comment: You are right. It is important to understand why this is not working. I am using .Net Core, Entity Framework Core and Visual Studio 2017RC. May be this is the reason it is not working? I did not try it on other .Net frameworks.